# Removing/replacing multi-line code sections with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove multiple lines containing an obsoleted code fragment from various file with the help of python. I looked for some examples but could not really find what I was looking for. What I basically need is something that does in principle the following (contains non-python syntax):

```
def cleanCode(filepath):
"""Clean out the obsolete or superflous 'bar()' code."""
with open(filepath, 'r') as foo_file:
    string = foo_file[index_of("bar("):]
    depth = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == "(": depth += 1
        if char == ")": depth -= 1
        if depth == 0: last_index = current_char_position
with open(filepath,'w') as foo_file:
    mo_file.write(string)
```

The thing is that the construct I'm parsing for and want to replace *could* contain other nested statements that also need to be removed as part of the `bar(...)` removal.

Here is what a sample, to be cleaned, code snippet would look like:

```
annotation (
  foo1(k=3),
  bar(
    x=0.29,
    y=0,
    bar1(
    x=3, y=4),
    width=0.71,
    height=0.85),
  foo2(System(...))
```

I would think that someone might have solved something similar before :)

Comment: Unless you have thousands complicated expressions like that, it's probably simpler to do by hand, maybe aided by `sed`. And if the problem *is* massive enough to justify a proper solution, the *real* proper solution is constructing an AST, modifying it, and converting it back to code. Fool-proof, easy, mostly already done in the stdlib, but requires understanding and may require extra work when you need an exotic coding style for the output.

Comment: Is the code you are working on also Python code?  If no, what is it?

Comment: I'd suggest you to describe what you want to do instead of just jumping on how are you trying to do it. This seems like sometime you would do with a regex replace in your editor/IDE or using a refactor tool.

Comment: Your code fragment reads the contents of a file into a string, runs a loop that does not modify the string, and then writes the unmodified string back to the same file.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @delnan: How would you find a string enclosed by balanced parentheses with sed?

Comment: related for sed or any other regex-based solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: @SvenMarnach I couldn't reasonably, hence "maybe".

Comment: @KurzedMetal Yes you are right I should not have provided my half-baked attempt which currently does nothing like SvenMarnach correctly noted. And yes I need to do this on LOADS of files. And will need to do so later on again (basically for cleaning up tool generated gibberish from time to time). So I would have done it with sed if not the multiple line nature of the problem normally means it does not work well with sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyparsing has some built-ins for matching nested parenthetical text - in your case, you aren't really trying to extract the content of the parens, you just want the text between the outermost '(' and ')'.

```
from pyparsing import White, Keyword, nestedExpr, lineEnd, Suppress

insource = """
annotation (
  foo1(k=3),
  bar(
    x=0.29,
    y=0,
    bar1(
    x=3, y=4),
    width=0.71,
    height=0.85),
  foo2(System(...))
"""

barRef = White(' \t') + Keyword('bar') + nestedExpr() + ',' + lineEnd

out = Suppress(barRef).transformString(insource)
print out
```

Prints

```
annotation (
  foo1(k=3),
  foo2(System(...))
```

EDIT: parse action to not strip bar() calls ending with '85':

```
barRef = White(' \t') + Keyword('bar') + nestedExpr()('barargs') + ','
def skipEndingIn85(tokens):
    if tokens.barargs[0][-1].endswith('85'):
        raise ParseException('ends with 85, skipping...')
barRef.setParseAction(skipEndingIn85)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering if one could also provide a tuple of Keywords. So for example if I wanted to match 'bar()' and/or 'foo2()'.

Comment: Paul one more question to your nice library, I tried to extend the `nestedExpr` to mach some special cases but for some reason `nestedExpr('(','85)')` will not match the 'bar' example above. Here the whole barRef I used: `barRef = ZeroOrMore(White(' \t')) + Keyword('bar') + nestedExpr('(','85)') + ',' + ZeroOrMore(White(' \t') + lineEnd )`

Comment: THe closing string in nestedExpr is supposed to be the closing string of *every* nested parenthesis, not just the last one, and your embedded parens ends in '4)', not '85)'.  As for matching various keywords, just change `Keyword('bar')` to `(Keyword('bar')|Keyword('baz')|Keyword('foo2'))`.

Comment: Ah I see. Well how would one then restrict the removal to only those 'bar' constructs that end with '`85)'`?

Comment: Add a parse action to the nestedExpr that looks at the last outermost token (probably tokens[0][-1]) to see if it 85, and if it isn't raise a ParseException.  `if tokens[0][-1] != '85': raise ParseException('must end in 85')`. Look at the docs to see how to add a parse action.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I'm gonna need some more time to digest the parse actions and how to set them up properly.

Comment: Hi Paul, OK I tried what you said. Problem is that when I raise a `ParseException` on the embedded parens (since it does not end on 85) the script will stop looking for further nested Expressions and therefor will not do any replacing. I guess what I would need is something that is "weaker" than `ParseException` wthat will allow the `setParseAction` to continue UNTIL it finds the nested expression ending on the correct token. I don't know if pyparsing has such a mechanism. I have not been able to find it in the docs though.

Comment: Dietmar, this is not consistent with my experience, I think we'll need to dig a little deeper into what your parse action is doing.

Comment: Ok, I added the parse action to the overall bar expression instead of nestedExpr. That avoids too many '85' tests on all nestings.

Comment: OK that was helpful, I mistakenly defined the parse action like this: `barRef = White(' \t') + Keyword('bar') + nestedExpr().setParseAction(foo) + ',' + lineEnd` which seems to make a difference. Also there was a slight misunderstanding due to me not expressing myself properly. I wanted to remove all nested expressions ending with `85` even if they contained more nested expressions but not the ones in which they were nested them self. Bu a simple `if not tokens.bar....` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
clo=0
def remov(bar):
   global clo
   open_tag=strs.find('(',bar) # search for a '(' open tag
   close_tag=strs.find(')',bar)# search for a ')' close tag
   if open_tag > close_tag:
      clo=strs.find(')',close_tag+1)
   elif open_tag < close_tag and open_tag!=-1:
      remov(close_tag)



f=open('small.in')
strs="".join(f.readlines())
bar=strs.find('bar(')
remov(bar+4)
new_strs=strs[0:bar]+strs[clo+2:]
print(new_strs)
f.close()
```

output:

```
annotation (
  foo1(k=3),
  foo2(System(...))
```

Comment: Thanks Aswini, this would have done the job if there would not been pyparsing which is even more comfortable :)